# Codeship basic build hanging

Tags: deployment, dependency-management, codeship

I am working on a project that uses Codeship to deploy builds. I got up today and saw: [image]

Normally a build takes ~2 minutes, but I have waited on this one for half an hour. Codeship does not show anything being run. Not a single command. And my integration does not show the new application version, either.

How can I fix the hanging build?

Comment: Could you send us a ticket at https://helpdesk.codeship.com so we can look into this? Usually stopping and restarting the build should do the trick as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed! I just had to stop and restart the build as well as reset the dependency cache. Thanks [@mlocher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2042725/mlocher) for the help.

If anyone came here from a search engine or something else with the same problem, try to restart the build, restart after resetting the dependency cache, or making another commit with a trivial / no change. This should fix the problem. Otherwise, send codeship a ticket at [helpdesk.codeship.com](https://helpdesk.codeship.com/).